# How to add library for yocto poky?

Tags: cmake, raspberry-pi, shared-libraries, yocto

Here is my cmake file

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.16.3)

project("Listing compressed files")

add_executable(list list.c)

target_link_libraries( list archive )
```

I'm getting this :
fatal error: archive.h: No such file or directory 5 | #include <archive.h>

Comment: sharing your bitbake recipe could help too.

Comment: @vermaete I'm a beginner so I'm not sure what it means. I run this command . /opt/poky/3.1.3/environment-setup-aarch64-poky-linux . After this cmake compiles for Raspi.

Comment: You do not provide enough information for us to answer your question.  How did you set up your environment? What files did you add? Which commands did you run? Providing this information in a step-by-step manner will help us help you.

Comment: I work with yocto poky daily so I can kinda guess what happens here. @Ola is correct when s/he points out the lack of information in the OP. The key is in the script you source for the environment. It contains some whacky stuff to cross compile your project. I’m not sure if it’s okay for you to disclose the entire script here. Let me make sure when I get to work in a few hours. I’ll try explaining clearly. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I work with yocto poky daily so I know what's going on here. At the time I write this answer, I'm unable to edit the OP since "Suggested edit queue is full". So I'll just fill in the details here.

The OP lacks important information regarding the problem at hand. Here's my guess:

---

```c
// list.c

// ...
// Line 5 below
#include <archive.h>
// ...
```

```
# CMakeLists.txt: same as OP

cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.16.3)

project("Listing compressed files")

add_executable(list list.c)

target_link_libraries( list archive )
```

You mentioned in the comment section that a script was source so that it can compile successfully. Without the script, you get the error `no such file or directory: archive.h`. So what's going on here?

The reason behind this is quite simple actually, and the secret lies in the sourced script.

Here's the relevant lines in that file:
(Note: I'm using 2.4.2. Yours is 3.1.3. But it should be very similar.)

```sh
export PATH=/opt/poky/2.4.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin:/opt/poky/2.4.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/sbin:/opt/poky/2.4.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/bin:/opt/poky/2.4.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/sbin:/opt/poky/2.4.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/../x86_64-pokysdk-linux/bin:/opt/poky/2.4.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/aarch64-poky-linux:/opt/poky/2.4.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/aarch64-poky-linux-musl:$PATH
export SDKTARGETSYSROOT=/opt/poky/2.4.2/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux
export CC="aarch64-poky-linux-gcc  -march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a57.cortex-a53 --sysroot=$SDKTARGETSYSROOT"
export CXX="aarch64-poky-linux-g++  -march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a57.cortex-a53 --sysroot=$SDKTARGETSYSROOT"
export CPP="aarch64-poky-linux-gcc -E  -march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a57.cortex-a53 --sysroot=$SDKTARGETSYSROOT"
export AS="aarch64-poky-linux-as "
export LD="aarch64-poky-linux-ld  --sysroot=$SDKTARGETSYSROOT"
export CFLAGS=" -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types "
export CXXFLAGS=" -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types "
export LDFLAGS="-Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed"
```

And the script goes on. As you can see here, when you source this file, lots of environment variables are set. I don't want to confuse you, so I won't go so far to comment why setting these variables like this is not a good thing to do in general.

Instead I'll just explain why you can build your code with these variables, but not without.

`CC` and `CXX` sets the compiler linux use to build your code. They are set to use the cross-compile toolchain provided by `/opt/poky`, as they are added at the front of `PATH`. `LD` and `AS` set the linkers, in case you wonder.

Going on, note how the script also sets `--sysroot=` option. In a word, it tells the compiler and linker to use this sysroot path (`/opt/poky/.../sysroots/aarch64-poky-inux`) as a search start. This will lead the cross-compilation toolchains, e.g. `aarch64-poky-linux-gcc` to search for header files like `archive.h` in question in `/opt/poky/..../aarch64-poky-linux/usr/include`, aka `SYSROOT_DIR/usr/include`, instead of the usual `/usr/include` without this option. (The `--sysroot=` option is quite commonly used during cross-compilation)

Even more, the poky environment also contains `archive.h` in `SYSROOT_DIR/usr/include` & `libarchive.so` in `SYSROOT_DIR/usr/lib`.

Now with these environment settings I mention, your project can be successfully cross-compiled using the toolchain provided.

---

The final mystery is why you can't build your project without the environment. As it turns out, it's not quite a mystery at all. The reason is plain, simple & dull: you simply lack the header file `archive.h` on your real `/usr/include`. So your normal compiler, `gcc` most likely, can't find it there.

If you want to build your project also on your x86 linux machine, you only have to install the dependency. For example, on Ubuntu, one would just do:

`sudo apt install libarchive-dev`

to install the dependency. Then you can build on x86 successfully.

---

Now I've demystify the error you see, I feel obligated to tell you that setting these variables like `poky` does is generally not appropriate for modern projects. Modern C/C++ projects, when using cmake properly, can be easily ported cross platform without so much hassle, especially not needed to and shouldn't set `CFLAGS`, `CXXFLAGS`, `LDFLAGS`, etc. A cmake toolchain file is all you need. But this goes way out of scope of answering this particular question, so it's better to Google about it.

HTH.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I'm aware that compiler searcher for archive.h in /opt/poky/..../aarch64-poky-linux/usr/include. The  problem is archive.h is not present in that. How can I add libarchive library and its headers in /opt/poky/..../aarch64-poky-linux/usr/include ?

Comment: @RudranshSrivastava I'm confused. If the header is not present in `/opt/poky/.../usr/include`, why would your code compile successfully when you source the environment file as you mentioned in the comment in the OP? Can you find `archive.h` file anywhere in `/opt/poky`?

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear. When I compile using gcc, I'm able to compile this file, ie when it uses usr/include but when I cross compile using /opt/poky/.../usr/include, it is not able to compile as the library is not present there. How can I add library for  /opt/poky/.../usr/include ?

Comment: Then you can try cross compiling libarchive from source with the environment on.

Comment: ok so I'll set my environment by this commad /opt/poky/3.1.3/environment-setup-aarch64-poky-linux. After this can you tell be the steps to cross compile libarchive library?